# Plugin Class does not exists

Tags: magento2.4.3, before-plugin

I am creating plugin to alter API response in M2.4.3. I am trying to alter this functionality via plugin
**Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response** and function **prepareResponse**
My di.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response">
        <plugin name="vendor_apiresponses_extend_Webapi_rest_response" type="Vendor\ApiResponses\Plugin\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\UpdateResponse" />
    </type>
</config>
```

and plugin file is :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\ApiResponses\Plugin\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response;

use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response;

class UpdateResponse
{

    /**
     * @param Response $subject
     * @param $outputData
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforePrepareResponse(
        Response $subject,
        $outputData = null
    ): array
    {
        $newResponseStructure['body'] = $outputData;
        return $newResponseStructure;
    }
}
```

on calling I am facing following error:

```
Error: Class 'Vendor\ApiResponses\Plugin\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\UpdateResponse' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:60
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Vendor\\ApiResp...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php(174): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Vendor\\ApiResp...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(119): Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getPlugin('Magento\\Framewo...', 'vendor_apiresp...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Webapi/Rest/Response/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Interceptor->___callPlugins('prepareResponse', Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(108): Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Interceptor->prepareResponse(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy))
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callParent('launch', Array)
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#15 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('launch', Array, Array)
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#17 /var/www/html/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#18 {main}
```

What is missing in above ?

Comment: have you compiled the code? are you getting same error there?

Comment: No error on compilation. their is no error in the code. might be issue in my local infra level. I created new module and its working. I check everything on local to find the issue at local but did not found anything.